# Facebook publish post with link and big image

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I use Koala to publish a **post with link** to a **Facebook Group**

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)

@graph.put_connections(group_id, "feed", {
              :message   => post_message,
              :picture   => backdrop,
              :link      => url
            })
```

I get this post

[image]

Instead I have to do this

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the FAQ of this document [Image Optimization for Link Page Posts](http://www.dicasinternet.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Facebook-Docs-Image-Optimization-for-Link-Page-Posts.pdf).

> **What is the minimum image size required to generate a link share post with a large image?**
>
> 600 x 315px is the minimum size that we require. However, we recommend
> that you use images that are at least 1200 x 630px for the best
> display on retina and high-resolution screens.
>
> **What will happen if the image is below the minimum requirements?**
>
> If the image is smaller than 600 x 315px, we will render it at 154 x
> 154px or smaller on mobile or desktop.
>
> [image]

Comment: PDF Link is not valid anymore, here is the official [Docs Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices/#images)